# Replacing the Visual/Text Editor for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, editor

I would like to create a custom post type where the posts are formatted as numbered lists on the front-end and in the WP Dashboard editor.

So, in the Dashboard, rather than the standard WP GUI/Text editor box for adding/editing posts, I want a series of text boxes for 1, 2, 3, etc. that builds the post as an ordered list on the frontend.

like
Title:

---

1.

---

2.

---

3.

---

Is this possible?

To remove the standard editor I used:
'supports' => array('title','custom-fields','revisions',),
when creating my custom post type
so if instead I included:
'supports' => array('title','custom-fields','revisions','listTypeItems'),
is there a way to set up the custom field(s) listTypeItems
if not is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

I know they have a 'Repeater Field' option that you have to buy for $10.00, which would allow you to continue adding text boxes, (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5...etc.)

If you know you just need three, then this plugin will allow you to create a custom interface on the admin panel where you can design the input boxes and such.

Then, you can create a custom post template, and insert the proper PHP tags to show your data on the page.

Here is the documentation for the plugin. I use it, and it's great!
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/getting-started/